# Linux-based distributions dedicated to video editing?

Tags: linux, video

I love Linux, but find that sometimes video editing tools I installed are crashing, probably because I did not configure them (or the system parameters) properly for professional video editing.

What Linux-based distributions are up-to-date, and dedicated to video processing?

Comment: This question is too broad with such a meager set of requirements: any major Linux distribution will do, just install the software that you want. What distribution(s) did you try, and in what way were they not satisfactory? What software do you want to run? Have you checked if the authors of that software have recommendations, maybe implicitly in the form of builds for some distributions?

Comment: This question is mentioned in the meta thread [Is recommending operating systems allowed on this site?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-recommending-operating-systems-allowed-on-this-site)

Comment: @Gilles: I asked for distributions DEDICATED to video editing, so your "any major Linux" answer is off-topic. "Ubuntu studio" is a great answer. There might be 1 or 2 other distributions dedicated to video editing, but not more than 5 I am sure, so "too many possible answers" is not a valid close reason. Builds are not enough, as professional software usually requires some specific kernel parameters and ulimit settings, for a start. Ubuntu studio does not exist for nothing.

Comment: If you interpret “dedicated” literally, then the answer is none. Any distribution will allow web browsing, word processing, etc. Video editing doesn't require anything in terms of parameters that other memory-demanding distributions don't. Yes, there are distributions that target video processing — but you haven't defined any requirements, which makes your question too broad for this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should give [Ubuntu studio](http://ubuntustudio.org) a try. It is not the most up to date but comes bundled with most of the packages you may want.

Otherwise, ArchLinux can be configured very well for Audio/Video editing. It has an [interesting wiki section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pro_Audio) about professional audio software and you can have pretty much any application made for Linux either in the official repositories or the AUR. It's harder to install the first time though.